# how to set screenOrientation of system activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, screen-orientation

I want to set screenOrientation of setting activity.

In my app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings"));
```

according above code, I can call setting activity.
but this activity's landscape is fixed. vertical.
I want change this activity's screenOrientation to horizontal(landscape).

Comment: am i getting it right? you want to rotate screen of activity after you set it on fixed ?

Comment: i don't think it is possible

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to open the Android Settings menu and fix the rotation when you launch it?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to the activity to decide what orientations it supports, not you. You can't limit an activity you start to particular orientations unless you can change the global setting for auto rotate (which you can't, as it's a system setting).